# Remove from single linked list via index

Tags: c#, generics, collections, linked-list

How to make insert to generic linked list via index without using tail.

```
public void RemoveByIndex(int index)
{
    int count = 0;
    LinkedListNode<T> current = Head;
    while (count <= index)
    {
        if (count == index)
        {
            current.Next = null;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }
        count++;
    }
    Head = current;
}
```

I've int list array with data 5, 10, 15. And I don't know why it always remove me 5,15 when I given him the 1'st index.

Comment: Why title says "add" when you actually removing from the list?

Comment: Edited, sorry, too much coding for today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First iteration (count = 0) => `else` block is executed => `current = current.next` => current = 10, current.next = 15

Second iteration (count=1) => `if` block is executed => `current.next = null` => 15 is removed => current = 10

At the end of second iteration count = 2 and you exit the while loop => `Head = current` => Head = 10 => 5 is removed

possible solution:

```
public void RemoveByIndex(int index)
{
   int count = 0;
   LinkedListNode<T> current = Head;
   LinkedListNode<T> previous = current;
   while (count <= index)
   {
       if (count == index)
       {
           previous.next = current.next               
           current = null;               
       }
       else
       {
           previous = current;
           current = current.Next;
       }           
       count++;
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1 = new LinkedList<int>();

var nodesToRemove = list1.Where(x => x == index).ToList();

foreach(var node in nodesToRemove)
        lis1.Remove(node);
```

Comment: Thanks but, but i'm making single linked list from scatch, with generic type and using Head.